# What is the relation between OS_PROCESS() and create_process() in OSE

Tags: c, ose

I have gone through the OSE documentation and find out that `create_process(parameter)` will create a process and return process id `pid` and there after `start(pid)` will start the created process. `OS_PROCESS(name)` is the entry point of the created process.

My question is what does the entry point mean here? How this comes into picture when sending and receiving signals? will this `OS_PROCESS(name)` be running all the time untill we kill the process? I know that by calling `receiver()` function we will wait for a signal to be received in the process.

Comment: The entry point of a process or thread is the *function* where the process/thread starts.

Comment: Then what start(pid) does ? isnt it the starting point of process/thread ?

Comment: It *starts* the process, but it isn't the actual *starting point* of the process. Lets make a car analogy: You *start* a car by using the ignition key, and drive from a *starting point*. The cars *starting point* is like the process *entry point*, and the ignition key of the car is like the `start` function to start a process.

Comment: OK, so we can only receive whatever the signals are sent to the **process pro**, under `OS_PROCESS(pro)` ?